# 2 player on same computer FIFA 13 online?

Tags: fifa-13

I have FIFA 13 (PC) and two controllers. Is it possible to play two players on same computer online versus other players? I can't find anywhere to have another player playing with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

1. Go to **Seasons**.
2. Pick **Play Season Match** and press Y(Triangle on PS3)
3. Change matchmaking settings to **Guests:Match mine**.